# Best approach for dynamic properties in LESS compiled css

Tags: html, css, less

I've got all of my styles made in .less which include a variable for each color that is used in multiple classes throughout the stylesheet. I am aware that this is generally compiled serverside and send as a normal .css to the client and heavily discouraged to compile clientside.

Now the task at hand. **Im trying to make it so that through settings i can change some base colors of my webapp**. I can imagine a few ways of doing this.

**a)** Going manually through all the css rules and replacing a specific color with js. Sounds tedious.

**b)** Having LESS in the browser, somehow changing the .less variables and again, somehow triggering a recompile of .less. This sounds likely.

**C)** This is probably stupid. Issuing a specific kind of request to the server that would cause it to recompile LESS with different settings ( ? ). Sounds unlikely that this is a valid approach. Also is problematic as the page would need to reload.

Does the fact that im using .less help at all in changing the theme dynamically? What is the recommended way of doing this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are settings changed per logged-in-user (etc), or across the entire app all at once?

Comment: its just a localstorage array of colors, its user/role agnostic. The idea is that this can hopefully somehow apply without reloading a page from the server by somehow ( dont know how yet ) tweaking the css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have preset color options, one possible method is to add a `data-` attribute to the `body` tag with the name of the preset color theme. Then use LESS to automatically generate the styles for all the color combinations.

The attribute is the only part that gets dynamically changed:

```
<body data-theme="blue">
```

In the LESS, first define your colors:

```
@theme-red:    #f00;
@theme-orange: #ffa500;
@theme-green:  #080;
@theme-blue:   #00f;
@theme-purple: #800080;
@theme-pink:   #ff69b4;
```

Then create an array of the theme names so you can loop through the options. Make sure the strings match the color variable names above:

```
@theme-options: 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink';
@theme-count: length(@theme-options);
```

Then create a mixin that is used to generate the styles for all themes.

Note that there is a default option supplied in case there is no valid `data-theme` attribute. This way you can have one of your colors be the default and/or you can define other default styles easily. This part isn't totally necessary if you are already defining default styles, but I found it useful, so I included it just in case it can help you:

```
.theme-color (@property, @default: @theme-blue) {
    & { @{property}: @default; }
    .loop-themes();
}

.loop-themes (@i: @theme-count) when (@i > 0) {
    .loop-themes((@i - 1));
    @color: extract(@theme-options, @i);
    @theme-var: 'theme-@{color}';

    body[data-theme=@{color}] & { @{property}: @@theme-var; }
}
```

Anywhere in the rest of your CSS that you are defining a "dynamic" style, just use the mixin like this when you want to use the preset default:

```
a {
    .theme-color(background-color);
}
```

... and like this when you want to use a custom value for the default:

```
a {
    .theme-color(background-color, #000);
}
```

Of course, the one downside to this is that all of your styles for all the colors are loaded no matter which theme you're using, but it's up to you to decide if it's worth it or not.

Answer (score 0):

First off you cant run LESS in the browser. LESS gets processed into css before it ever gets to the page.

However I offer a alternative:

```js
var changeColor = function(){
  var element = document.getElementById('btn1');
  var color = element.getAttribute('color');
  if(color === 'blue'){
    element.setAttribute('color', 'red');
  } else {
    element.setAttribute('color', 'blue');
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-size:20px;
}

[color="blue"] {
  background-color:blue;
}

[color="red"] {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1" class="button" onclick="changeColor()">color change</button>
```

This code only severs as an example of how you could set up the css selectors. Basically you separate the colors into a different class/selector.

In my cause whenever the attribute is changed the color will change along with it. As long as the selector is defined.

This works great is you have a bunch of pre-defined values. But not so great if you want any color. In that case you could probably change the style of the element it's self. For example:

```
element.style.color = 'Some user input value';
```

To bring it all together you will probably need some script (JavaScript so you can run it when the user changes the color choice) that changes all of the correct elements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Quick correction : you CAN run a less compiler in the browser. http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser

Comment: The reason i was thinking of somehow combining this with less is that all the predefined colors that might be present in more than 20 elemnts each are neatly tidied up and grouped in the top of the less file and therefore going through each element one by one sounds tedious when the color needs to be specifically set by the user.